# Show/hide an element after page load in a dynamic page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a server side web application that shows a listing with some filters. I would like to add a "Reset" button when a filter item is clicked and then I want the Reset button to disappear when the Reset button is clicked. I thought I can accomplish it with this:

```
$('.sort-by-agency ul li a').click(function() {
    $('.sort-by-agency ul').after(viewAllBtn);
});
$('.sort-by-agency .view-all').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

But this doesn't work and it makes the Reset button to only appear for a second once a filter is clicked. The filter click makes the page to reload, and that makes the Rest button to disappear quickly.  Is there a way to trigger the on click when ".sort-by-agency ul li a" link is clicked but load the function after the page is reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

When the page reloads, the state of the app will be lost. So you have to prevent the page from reloading when the filter is clicked.
for accomplishing that, you should change your first function to this:

```
$('.sort-by-agency ul li a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.sort-by-agency ul').after(viewAllBtn);
});
```

Learn more about this from jQuery docs : [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: But if I prevent the default function of the link then the filter is not going to work

Comment: they are generated by the CMS

Comment: Have you tried the solution I provided and it made the filters to stop working?
Or you are just guessing it?

Comment: I tried that before I posted the question. It does interrupt the default action of the filter.